# Get distinct values based on selected field with LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following table

```
Members
    Id, GroupId, Age
    1,    1,     12
    2,    1,     20
    3,    1,     33
    4,    2,     12
    5,    2,     7
```

How can I write a LINQ query that will give me a list of the oldest member of each group?

The result should be

```
    Id, GroupId, Age
    3,    1,     33
    4,    2,     12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from m in members
group m by m.GroupId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Age).First()
```